# How to rotate pie chart with mouse wheel in JFreeChart?

Tags: java, charts, jfreechart

I'm searching about a pie chart that is rotated by mouse wheel but couldn't find a good example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `ChartPanel` method [`setMouseWheelEnabled(true)`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/ChartPanel.html#setMouseWheelEnabled%28boolean%29).

Addendum: [`PieChartDemo1`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/demo/PieChartDemo1.html), included in the distribution, is a complete example; click the class name to see the [source](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/src-html/org/jfree/chart/demo/PieChartDemo1.html#line.185).